# writeToFile in OSX, appending to the file?

Tags: cocoa, macos, file

I need to write some data from time to time to a file, appending to it.

Right now I have:

```
BOOL ok = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",raw] writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
```

How could I append to the end of the file the new contents of `raw`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method would be to obtain a NSFileHandle using fileHandleForWritingAtPath: method, converting  your NSString to NSData and then calling writeData: on your NSFileHandle after moving the file pointer to the end of the file.

Comment: Correct. -writeTo... methods overwrite the file with the contents being written. There is no "appendTo..." equivalent.

Comment: Although, I don't imagine it would be very hard to write a category method on NSString which implements an appendToFile...

Answer (score 22):

Here is an NSString category method that will append the receiver to the specified path with the specified encoding (normally NSUTF8StringEncoding).

```
- (BOOL) appendToFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    if ( !fh ) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    }
    if ( !fh ) return NO;
    @try {
        [fh seekToEndOfFile];
        [fh writeData:[self dataUsingEncoding:enc]];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        result = NO;
    }
    [fh closeFile];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for supplying the code that does the job.  (IMO, this should be the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Li'l edit to Peter N Lewis Answer:

```
- (BOOL) appendToFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    if ( !fh ) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    }
    if ( !fh ) return NO;
    @try {
        [fh seekToEndOfFile];
        [fh writeData:[strcontent dataUsingEncoding:enc]];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        result = NO;
    }
    [fh closeFile];
    return result;
}
```

Call Where ever you want

```
 [self appendToFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcontent` may be `self` when you put this method to a Catagory of NSString.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Swift version, not exactly the same, but it works.  I decided not to extend String so that it could be used as an alternate to write(exportFileNameURL: URL, str: String)

```
fileprivate static func appendToFile(_ exportFileName: String, str: String) -> Bool {
    let result : Bool = true;
    if let fh : FileHandle = FileHandle.init(forWritingAtPath: exportFileName) {
        fh.seekToEndOfFile()
        fh.write(str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        fh.closeFile()
    }
    else {
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        if let fh = FileHandle.init(forWritingAtPath: exportFileName) {
            fh.seekToEndOfFile()
            fh.write(str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            fh.closeFile()
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return result
}
```