# How to modify csv file programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to modify (Add a new row) existing csv file in xcode. i have created a csv file programmatically , but when i try to modify it , it delete all the previos data.

i am opening an existing csv file and want to add a next row.

NSString *docFile = [DOCS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Questions_Logs.csv"];
NSFileManager* filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//---get the contents of file and if content avalbl than append new data and save it--

```
if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:docFile])
```

{

```
 NSArray *arrCSV = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:strName,strAge,strDesig, nil];
 [[arrCSV componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:docFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

}

```
else
```

{
       NSArray *arrCSV = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"Age",@"Designation", nil];
     [[arrCSV componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:docFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
  }

Comment: We probably need to see some code. A guess, though: Are you opening the file for writing as opposed to appending?

Comment: You haven't said which language you're using, but when opening files, you usually have to specify a mode. Look at the 'mode' section in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen

Comment: what in your question has anything to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_134

"This method overwrites any existing file at path."

See [writeToFile in OSX, appending to the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626697/writetofile-in-osx-appending-to-the-file) for the solution.