# Writing to log file seems to overwrite previous save

Tags: swift, logging, writetofile

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a logging class that logs strings to a text file. I've got my application to write and read from the file.  However, if I try to log multiple times it seems to only pick up the most recent log.

**Attempt**

*writing*

```
private let file = "logfile.txt"

func write(text: String) {

    let path = getDocumentsDirectory()

    do {
        try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch let error {
        print("error: \n \(error)")
    }
}
```

*reading*

```
func read() {

    let path = getDocumentsDirectory()

    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print("From Log: \n \(text2)")
    }
    catch let error {
        print("error: \n \(error)")
    }


}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String {
    guard let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first else {
        return ""
    }
    let documentsDirectory : String = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

**Result**

When I try to read my file I only get the last line saved.

### Question

If my goal is to endlessly append new logs to a file, and to read the log file in bulk. What changes to my code do I need to make?

---

**more details:**

I'm writing to the file on application load:

```
Logger.shared.write("instance one writes")
Logger.shared.write("instance one writes again")
Logger.shared.write("instance one writes yet again")
```

and then attempting to read:

```
Logger.shared.read()
```

output:

> From Log:
>    instance one writes yet again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writeToFile in OSX, appending to the file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626697/writetofile-in-osx-appending-to-the-file)

Comment: On the contrary, you are using exactly the same method (`writeToFile(_:atomically:encoding:)`) which produces exactly the same problem, and I would recommend exactly the same solution (`NSFileHandle`). The language difference is hardly worth noting, especially since the accepted answer provides a place to look in the docs, and not actual code.

Comment: Here is another similar question if you like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779877/how-to-write-in-append-mode-for-text-file

Comment: @jtbandes I can't find a single example of someone using NSFileHandle in Swift the way it is in your two posts. .fileHandleForWritingAtPath is unavailable in Swift.

Comment: It's an initializer rather than a static method; the Obj-C and equivalent Swift syntax are given in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleForWritingAtPath:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `writeToFile(_:atomically:encoding:)` method provided by Foundation *replaces* the contents of the given file. There are several ways of *appending* to files:

- Plain ol’ [`fopen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fopen.3.html) (with mode `"a"`) and [`fwrite`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fwrite.3.html).
- NSOutputStream, such as [`NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: mypath, append: true)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutputStream/initToFileAtPath:append:), using [`stream.write(bytes, len)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331636/writing-a-string-to-an-nsoutputstream-in-swift) to write data.
- Perhaps the easiest, NSFileHandle, such as [`NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: mypath)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleForWritingAtPath:), using [`seekToEndOfFile()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/seekToEndOfFile) and [`writeData()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/writeData:).

Comment: I appreciate your time, sorry for being difficult.

Comment: No problem. Apologies for curtness — it's often hard to judge when it's worth rewriting answers for Swift, because these APIs are identical in functionality to the Obj-C ones (just a different syntax), so good answers often exist already in the wrong language. For every Swift app developer's sake, I recommend they gain at least a little [familiarity with Obj-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) — the ability to read *just enough* Obj-C to translate to Swift is immensely useful.

Comment: I definitely plan on it, I'm still taking Swift classes right now so the Cocoa framework is all new to me. Thanks again.

Comment: I would recommend browsing the articles on http://nshipster.com/ — almost all their code samples are in both Obj-C and Swift so you can compare them easily. And you'll learn some things about Cocoa at the same time :)